# Make the browser complain on invalid html input

Tags: html, w3c

I am just wondering weather there is a way to validate html input. I tried W3Cs html validator, but it does not seem to be very useful. For example it did not complain about a table division with rowspan set to 7 in a table which has just one row.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head><title>adsf</title></head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td rowspan="7">asdf</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I wonder if there is a way to automatically detect invalid html constructs such as the one above.

Comment: you'll need to write a script which can check HTML code following some rules , as you defined "if there's rowspan , check how much TR element exists..". It can be a really nice project.

Comment: The rowspan = 7 example is perfectly valid HTML. Logically its wrong, but syntactically it's fine.

Comment: W3C 17.5 overlapping cells in a table are called illegal. So I would not say it is valid.

Comment: @OfirBaruch Well I hope that somebody already did this..

Comment: Try using HTML5. The validator for that is clever enough to check for that and correctly reports a validation error. In earlier versions of HTML, it was not invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about syntax (or a lexer), as far as I know, W3C is roughly a parser, which is not designed to check these kind of constraints.